# Casting list as string in POST request works, but leaving it as list doesn't

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out why this constitutes a valid POST request:

```
    pk = 5
    data = {
        'ids': str([pk]),
        'latitude': 0,
        'longitude': 0,
    }
    response = self.client.post(
        '/api/{}/endpoint'.format(settings.DEFAULT_VERSION),
        data=json.dumps(data, indent=4),
        content_type='application/json',
        HTTP_AUTHENTICATION=user.access_token,
    )
```

whereas this doesn't:

```
    pk = 5
    data = {
        'ids': [pk],
        'latitude': 0,
        'longitude': 0,
    }
    response = self.client.post(
        '/api/{}/endpoint'.format(settings.DEFAULT_VERSION),
        data=json.dumps(data, indent=4),
        content_type='application/json',
        HTTP_AUTHENTICATION=user.access_token,
    )
```

The latter results in the following error: "TypeError: expected string or buffer".

On the server side, the second line seems to be failing:

```
    ids_json = request.data.get('ids')
    ids = json.loads(ids_json)
```

I'm not sure why casting the 'ids' list as a string works, but leaving it as a list doesn't.

Comment: That's how `json.loads` works, it expects a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are different jsons:

```
pk = 5
data = {
    'ids': str([pk]),
    'latitude': 0,
    'longitude': 0,
}
# json = {"latitude": 0, "longitude": 0, "ids": "[5]"}
```

While:

```
pk = 5
data = {
    'ids': [pk],
    'latitude': 0,
    'longitude': 0,
}
# json = {"latitude": 0, "longitude": 0, "ids": [5]}
```

The first one is actually a string, so you can pass it further to "json.loads". The second one is a list.

Comment: Ah! Why is the function able to coerce the IDs into a string, but doesn't complain about the latitude/longitude being integers?

Comment: Because you don't force the latitude/longitude to be strings, so they are simply numbers. You would have to cast them to string (eg: `'latitude': str(0),`) to be detected as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid post requests.

By using `json.loads(ids_json)` you are expecting `ids_json` to be a string.

`json.loads` parses a string into json

Answer (score 1):

```
pk = 5
data = {
    'ids': [pk],
    'latitude': 0,
    'longitude': 0,
}
response = self.client.post(
    '/api/{}/endpoint'.format(settings.DEFAULT_VERSION),
    data=json.dumps(data, indent=4),
    content_type='application/json',
    HTTP_AUTHENTICATION=peep.access_token,
)

# on server side, it seem like the request.data is already a dict type.
ids_json = request.data.get('ids')
# so ids_json is should be a list type, which you want to get.
```